# How to check number of live visitors for my asp.net website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, statistics

How do I check number of current visitors for my asp.net website? I am already familiar with following technique but its not close to accurate result.

- Create application variable  Application["UserCount"]
- Increase it in session start
- Decrease it in session end

This technique does not check whether the request comes from Web crawlers, robots or any other spammer servers which may request several pages in new sessions which kind of inflates the number.

I want to make sure that a person has opened up a browser (mobile or desktop) to view my website even if he is viewing other sites in same window or in different window but at least my site is open in at least one tab or one window.

Something like ajax hidden request maker that loads with each of my page and tells server that my site is open.

Thanks.

Comment: You could look into Google Analytics, but I don't know what their pricing model is like. I've used it before and it works nicely, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the user-agent on the request. You can use `Request.Browser.Crawler` to check if the request comes from a search engines crawler. It will return true if the browser is a crawler.

You could also use a javascript call to a page to update the visitor count. This could be combined with the above mentioned technique to ensure that visitor counts are only update if the request is a real user. You should also check that the request is not a crawler when you decrease the user count. For example

```
        //increase the user count
        if (Request.Browser.Crawler == false)
        {
            Application["user_count"] = +1;
        }

        //decrease the user count
        if (Request.Browser.Crawler == false)
        {
            Application["user_count"] = -1;
        }
```

You could also use the Session_End and Session_Start event in the application's global.asax file, to perform the same events.

Comment: This is not 100 percent accurate but seems close result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Application to store the data. It's totally fine for the early stage of the website or web application. However, you may need to look into multiple access issue to the application state when the site is loaded.